Do I need commas when doing a sort of funnel in a sentence
I am trying to point out the location of specific sentences in an article. My text is as follows:

Notable examples of this include Section 1 paragraph 1 sentences 2 & 3: "..."; Section 1 page 2 sentences 1 & 2: "...";

Should the sentence be written as Section 1, paragraph 1, sentences 2 & 3 or Section 1 paragraph 1 sentences 2 & 3?

Is either unclear? Style guides tend to recommend rather than demand commas in such cases.

May I ask, in what kind of writing would you be merely pointing out the location in that manner rather than quoting the sentences and putting some sort of location reference afterwards in parentheses or in a footnote, when a page number is not available?

@EdwinAshworth My preference was the option without commas but the concern was whether that was incorrect.

There's no 'punctuation czar' to demand a 'correct way' here. There are local potentates (tutors; editors) who may have definite localised rules, by-laws. One needs to check with them. Two rival editors may make conflicting demands. Otherwise, find well-written examples to mimic.

In my experience, the version with commas is more common.

Your quote and your question do not match.

You can google "Section 1 paragraph" etc and find both with and without a comma. Just be consistent.

Yes, I think list items in sentence form should be separated by commas:
Notable examples of this include Section 1, paragraph 1, sentences 2 & 3: "..."; Section 1, page 2, sentences 1 & 2: "...";
This is more of a style question than a grammar question, however...inserting commas to separate list items and items in series is a longstanding 'rule.' In the specific example in the question, the commas help with separating items that could become confused. You don't want a reader to see "page 1 paragraph 2 sentence 3-4" and possibly confuse the items and numerals.
